# How to print right side result continously in python?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I have my code:

```
for i in range(0,5):
    print "result is:"+str(i),
```

This prints:

```
result is:0 result is:1 result is:2 result is:3 result is:4
```

I want to print like this:

```
result is:0,1,2,3,4
```

How to do it in python?

Comment: I dont understand why negative vote for this question?

Comment: You should print "result is:" before the loop, if you want it only once ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
print('Result is: {}'.format(', '.join(map(str, range(5)))))
```

prints

```
Result is: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Valid for Python 2 and Python 3.

Explanation:

`range(5)` is the same as `range(0, 5)`. `map(str, x)`, given an iterable x, returns  a new iterable having all the items in x stringified (`e` -> `str(e)` ). `', '.join(iterable)` joins a given iterable (list, generator, etc) whose elements are strings, into a string 1 string using the given separator. Finally `str.format()` replaces the `{}` placeholders with its arguments in order.

Answer (score 4):

Since you want to print all the elements of the list, you can convert all the numbers to string and join all of them together with `,`, like this

```
print "result is:" + ",".join(str(number) for number in range(0, 5))
```

Since the `range`'s default start parameter is 0, you can call it like this

```
print "result is:" + ",".join(str(number) for number in range(5))
```

Also, you can use templated strings like this

```
print "result is: {}".format(",".join(str(number) for number in range(5)))
```

You can apply the `str` function to all the elements of the number list, with `map` function, like this

```
print "result is: {}".format(",".join(map(str, range(5)))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
x = 'result is: ';
for i in range(0,5):
    x += str(i) + ',';
print(x[:-1];
```

will do what you want. In a highly legible form although not the best speed possible.

Answer (score 1):

Another version of the same thing:

```
for i in range(0,5):
    if i == 0:
        print "result is %d" % i,
else:
    print ",%d" % i,
```

Comment: Thanks. If i dont know the range.Suppose if range is (1,5). The first value may be random.how to do it in this case

Answer (score 0):

In Python3 you can use the `end` kwarg of the [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function. This is not possible in Python2.

```
print("The result is: ", end="")
for i in range(5):
    print(str(i)+", ", end="")
```

Comment: it is if you import from future

Comment: it is possible in python2 via `print foo,` note the `,` at the end. That prevents it from printing new line.